# Why do native return types throw System.InvalidProgramException?

Tags: .net, interop, c++-cli

Why does this throw an InvalidProgramException? The different variants I've seen have said:

> 1. JIT has encountered an internal limitation.
> 2. Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

I've simplified the example to the minimum set of circumstances I can to reproduce the issue. You should be able to grab the below code and paste it into VS2010 to reproduce this.

Basic structure of below is that CppReferenceTest is a CLR DLL assembly that contains a method returning a native struct. Referee is a CLR console app attempting to invoke this method. Referee has a project reference to CppReferenceTest.

I know from other testing that invoking the method internal to CppReferenceTest will not throw an InvalidProgramException. I also know that if I change the method signature to take a reference parameter instead of having a return value, no exception is thrown.

## Assembly 1 - CppReferenceTest (CLR dll library)

File: NativeHeader.h

```
#pragma managed(push, off)

typedef struct _NativeStruct {
    int val1;
    int val2;
} NativeStruct;   

#pragma managed(pop)
```

File: CppReferenceTest.h

```
#pragma once

#include "NativeHeader.h"

using namespace System;

#pragma make_public(_NativeStruct)

namespace CppReferenceTest {

public ref class Class1
{
    public:
        static NativeStruct GetNativeEnum();
    };
}
```

File: CppReferenceTest.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "CppReferenceTest.h"

using namespace CppReferenceTest;

NativeStruct Class1::GetNativeEnum()
{
    NativeStruct ns = {1, 2};
    return ns;
}
```

## Assembly 2 - Referee (CLR console app)

File: Referee.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "NativeHeader.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace CppReferenceTest;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    NativeStruct ns = Class1::GetNativeEnum();
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET, type identity includes the assembly the type is loaded from.  Therefore, you should NOT use `#include` with managed references, only `#import` (the References tab in Project Settings is equivalent to `#import`).

What is happening now is that by `#include`-ing the header file, you promise that there is a `_NativeStruct` type in the current assembly.  Your `main` function uses this type.

Then, at runtime, the CLR discovers that `Class1::GetNativeEnum()` returns a different `_NativeStruct` type, defined in `CppReferenceTest.dll`.  These types aren't compatible, and you get the exception.

Just use the type provided in the metadata of the assembly you reference.

---

In addition to all that, don't do `typedef struct _NativeStruct NativeStruct` in C++.  It isn't necessary, it screws up error messages, and to make matters worse, it conflicts with a reserved identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I remove the `#include` I get a compile error `error C2065: 'NativeStruct' : undeclared identifier`. How can I get a reference to that native struct? I also notice if I change the signature to `Class1::GetNativeEnum([Out] NativeStruct& ns)` it works - possibly due to equivalent memory layout of the two native types?

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the `typedef` part. The struct matches a C struct I am interfacing to, so I am keeping the example as close to the actual problem as I can.

Comment: @Bringer128: That's somewhat odd.  Does it help if you use `#pragma make_public` in the client as well?

Comment: Nope, then we get `error C2157: '_NativeStruct' : must be declared before use in pragma list`.

Comment: @Bringer128: Maybe `#include` and `#pragma make_public` together?

Comment: That compiles, but gives me an `InvalidProgramException` again.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct, as it does address the issue of the invalid program.

Comment: @Bringer128: Sorry we haven't found a real solution yet, just your workaround of using an out argument.